# What is the general form of a tensor of the $n$-th rank? Is there a specific summation sequence for it?

Tags: tensors

While reading Griffiths Electrodynamics, I came across a formula for both $n=1$ and $2$ ranks. Which intrigued me if there is a general formula for a tensor.  Both $n=1$ and $2$ had a summation series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afraid not, no. [Most tensor problems are NP-hard.](https://arxiv.org/abs/0911.1393)

From wiki: "The only notable well-understood case consists of tensors in $ F^{I_{m}}\otimes F^{I_{n}}\otimes F^{2}$, whose rank can be obtained from the *Kronecker–Weierstrass normal form* of the linear matrix pencil that the tensor represents."

Source: Hillar, C. J.; Lim, L. (2013). "Most tensor problems are NP-Hard". Journal of the ACM. 60 (6): 1–39.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I will be reverting this back to unanswered, though your answer is satisfactory, just for finding interesting answers. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I guess the answer is quite old and I figured the logic out anyway.